# [Error]Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance. in laravel edit and update route

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to make edit and update in Laravel.
On the view "edit.blade.php" I wrote the route code but, it showed **Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.**
I checked my web.php, Controller and edit.blade.php but i couldn't find what is wrong...
please help me what is wrong...

```js
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['book.update','book_id'=>$books->id], 'method' => 'put']) !!}
```

```css
Route::get('/books',[BookController::class,'index'])->name('home.books');
Route::get('books/create', [BookController::class, 'create'])->name('book.create');
Route::get('/books/{book_id}', [BookController::class, 'show'])->name('book.show');
Route::post('/store',  [BookController::class, 'store'])->name('book.store');
Route::put('/books/{book_id}',  [BookController::class, 'update'])->name('book.update');
Route::delete('/books/destroy/{book_id}', [BookController::class, 'destroy'])->name('book.destroy');
Route::get('/books/edit/{book_id}', [BookController::class, 'edit'])->name('book.edit');
```

```html
 public function edit($book_id)
    {
        $books = Book::find($book_id);
        $books = Book::pluck('name','name');
        return view('front.book.edit',[
            'books' => $books
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $book_id)
    {
        $books = Book::find($book_id);

        $name = $request ->name;
        $title = $request ->title;
        $comments = $request ->comments;

        $books = new Book;
        $books -> name =$name;
        $books -> title=$title;
        $books -> comments=$comments;

        $books ->update();

        return redirect()->route('home.books')->with('message','修正しました');
    }
```

Comment: ``$books = Book::pluck('name','name');`` you're only keeping the ``name`` property which is why ``id`` doesn't exist. This line should be ``$books = Book::pluck('id', 'name');``.

Comment: Youre using `::pluck('name')` on your Book model, meaning you will only fetch the name of the books. Use `dd($books)` in your edit method if you wanna see what your books collection looks like